# R: Dividing heat map using colors with geom_tile() and scale_fill_gradientn()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am producing many heat maps which should all have the same color scheme, as follows:

- if x-axis value = y-axis value, fill with blue gradient
- if x-axis value > y-axis value, fill with yellow gradient
- if x-axis value < y-axis value , fill with red gradient

EDIT: It is important that each color gradients over their respective numbers. I.e in Example A below, 18, 20, and 25 are the "darkest" colors on the map.

My code is below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
graphdata$pct <-ifelse(graphdata$A-graphdata$B>=0,graphdata$n/sum(graphdata$n),-graphdata$n/sum(graphdata$n))
graphdata$color_group <- ifelse(graphdata$A-graphdata$B<0,1,
                                   ifelse(graphdata$A-graphdata$B>0,2,3))
    graphdata$rescale <- 100*graphdata$pct + 100*(graphdata$color_group-1)
    gradientends <-c(min(graphdata$rescale),
                     ifelse(dim(subset(graphdata,rescale<=0,select=c(rescale)))[1]==0,0,max(subset(graphdata,rescale<=0,select=c(rescale)))),
                     ifelse(dim(subset(graphdata,rescale>=100 & rescale<200,select=c(rescale)))[1]==0,0,min(subset(graphdata,rescale>=100 & rescale<200,select=c(rescale)))),
                     ifelse(dim(subset(graphdata,rescale>=100 & rescale<200,select=c(rescale)))[1]==0,0,max(subset(graphdata,rescale>=100 & rescale<200,select=c(rescale)))),
                     ifelse(dim(subset(graphdata,rescale>=200,select=c(rescale)))[1]==0,0,min(subset(graphdata,rescale>=200,select=c(rescale)))),
                     max(graphdata$rescale))
    
    colorends <- c("tomato1","lightpink1","lightgoldenrod1","goldenrod1","lightsteelblue1","steelblue2")
        
    ggplot(data = graphdata, aes(x = as.factor(A), y = as.factor(B))) +
          geom_tile(aes(fill = rescale), colour = "white") + 
          scale_fill_gradientn(colors=colorends,values=rescale(gradientends)) +
          theme(legend.position = "none", 
                axis.text=element_text(size=12,face="bold"), 
                panel.background = element_blank(),
                axis.ticks=element_blank(), 
                plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)) + 
          geom_text(aes(label=n)) +labs(x="A",y="B")
```

My code works when there is data that can be bucketed in all three categories (Example A), but it fails to color correctly when there are 2 or less categories in the data (Example B).

#### Example A

```
A <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,2,1,3)
B <- c(1,2,3,2,3,2,1,3,1)
n <- c(10,5,20,15,18,10,10,10,25)

graphdata <- data.frame(A,B,n)
rm(A,B,n)
```

gives me what I'm expecting:
[image]

#### Example B

```
A <- c(1,2,3)
B <- c(1,2,3)
n <- c(10,5,20)

graphdata <- data.frame(A,B,n)
rm(A,B,n)
```

does not give me a blue gradient:
[image]

I would like Example B to look more like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise using `alpha` to scale your colors. This makes the problem *much* simpler:

```
cols <- c('-1' = "tomato1", '0' = "steelblue2", '1' = "goldenrod1")

ggplot(graphdata, aes(x = as.factor(A), y = as.factor(B))) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = as.factor(sign(A-B)), alpha = n), colour = "white") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
    geom_text(aes(label = n)) +
    labs(x = "A", y = "B") +
    theme_minimal() + 
    theme(legend.position = 'none', panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is close to what I'm looking for. I need each color to gradient over the numbers in their respective sections (so 18, 20, and 25 should be the darkest colors on the graph, not just 25). I tried adding `breaks=` to scale_fill_manual, but that didn't work. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I figured it out - I rescaled n for each section and then use that rescaled value in alpha. Thanks so much for your help! This definitely simplified my code

Comment: Yes exactly, that is the way to go.